# Hide hyperref internal links but apply a border to external links?

Tags: hyperref

I know that I can use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to turn off borders for all links generated by the `hyperref` pacakge, but is there a way to turn off borders only for *internal* links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options (`urlbordercolor`, `runbordercolor`, `allbordercolors`) that define the boxes, perhaps that is what you are looking for. Also, if you define the color for a class of links, the box dissapears. Look at the hyperref manual, at the end of section 2.

Comment: yes, but these just set the *colour* of the border, they don't turn it on and off...

Comment: If you set the border white? Or invisible? (Next idea is go hacking into the code, and I shudder...)

Comment: Adding a white border results in artefacts. But, if I use `linkcolor=black`, that will achieve what I want for the internal links. Thanks!

Comment: If you got your problem solved, answer your own question and accept it later to close the issue.